# Migration to Angular2 -> advice required

Tags: angularjs, angular

Some background:

I having part in developing a huge, extremely dynamic and customizable Angular 1 web application.

Since it so huge and dynamic, there are tons of watchers out there - 4K in single view, at least.

As may be expected, the application is suffering from major performance problems. This huge amount of watchers make application loading and general response times to be very long.

As one possible solution, I was considering to upgrade several of "heavy" components to Angular2 - so these parts could live in ng2 framework and use ng2 change tracking - which is much faster.

While reading migration [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html), I noticed this paragraph:

> When we downgrade an Angular 2 component and then use it from Angular 1, the component's inputs will be watched using Angular 1 change detection.

At this point I want to get advice, just to make sure I'm taking right decisions:

Since I not going to convert the whole application at once, but to convert incrementally (directive by directive), which direction I should take in order to benefit ng2 performance improvements (e.g. ng2 change tracking):

- a. Should I migrate "bottom-up", e.g. top level components will
  remain ng1; while lower level will be converted to ng2, or

  - b.
    Migrate    "from up to the bottom"

Personally I prefer first option (sounds to me less risky), but in case the shell will remine ng1 while its content will be converted to ng2 - isn't that means (according to documentation) that I will be forced to use ng1 change tracking mechanics inside ng2 components? Or I get it wrong?

From your experience, which migration direction proves itself better?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should at first experiment yourself. If ngUpgrade/ngDowngrade works well in your situation is hard to tell without knowing all details. I have seen discussions that it's not working very well for components beyond very simple examples but I  haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm a bit late to the party here. The ngUpgrade stuff by the Angular team is absolutely fantastic and a viable solution, however I think it'll create more work that perhaps it may be worth (depending on the size of your application).

What I'd shoot for would be a modular process of upgrading a single module at a time rather than components/services at a time. i.e. assuming your 1.x app is broken up into modules you can begin rewriting the first module for example a "dashboard" module or "inbox" module. I went through this process before and we rewrote the homepage of our application, and once the user needed to hit another page that was the "legacy code", the url had `/v1/` in to show that they'd actually gone to another application. This way we technically had two applications but ran them completely separate.

If you're still looking at concepts etc to upgrade, I've been working on an Angular 1.x to [Angular 2 migration guide](http://ngmigrate.telerik.com) which may help you on your way :)

Comment: can you please answer this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690591/how-to-access-a-formgroup-in-html-to-pass-to-a-component-added-dynamically